# LocalizationUtil not able to get the text if unescape the xml document

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, liferay-6

I am using the following API to get localization and one of my values in xml have a & symbol (ISV OEM & Resell).

```
String trpname="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><root available-locales='bg_BG,cs_CZ,de_DE,el_GR,en_GB,es_ES,es_MX,fr_FR,hr_HR,hu_HU,in_ID,it_IT,ja_JP,ko_KR,pl_PL,pt_BR,pt_PT,ro_RO,ru_RU,sk_SK,tr_TR,zh_CN,zh_TW' default-locale='en_US'>"       
        +"    <name language-id='bg_BG'>ISV OEM и Препродажба</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='cs_CZ'>ISV OEM a prodej</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='de_DE'>ISV, OEM &amp; Wiederverkauf</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='el_GR'>ISV OEM &amp; Μεταπωλητές</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='en_GB'>ISV OEM &amp; Resell</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='es_ES'>OEM de ISV y Distribución</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='es_MX'>ISV OEM y Reventa</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='fr_FR'>OEM ISV et revente</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='hr_HR'>ISV proizvođač originalne opreme i preprodaja</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='hu_HU'>ISV OEM és viszonteladó</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='in_ID'>OEM ISV OEM &amp; Penyaluran</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='it_IT'>Rivenditori e OEM ISV</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='ja_JP'>ISV OEMおよび再販</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='ko_KR'>ISV OEM 및 리셀</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='pl_PL'>ISV OEM i sprzedaż</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='pt_BR'>OEM &amp; Revenda de ISV</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='pt_PT'>ISV OEM e Revenda</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='ro_RO'>OEM şi revânzare ISV</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='ru_RU'>Услуги независимых OEM-поставщиков ПО</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='sk_SK'>ISV OEM a predaj</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='tr_TR'>ISV OEM ve Satış</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='zh_CN'>ISV OEM 和转售</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='zh_TW'>ISV OEM 與經銷</name>"
        +"    <name language-id='en_US'>ISV OEM &amp; Resell</name>"
        +"</root>";
        String translatedProgramName = HtmlUtil.unescape(trpname);
        String programName = LocalizationUtil.getLocalization(translatedProgramName, "en_US");
```

my user locale is right now en_US ,checked with logs. I observed that if i do not do unescape of xml doccument than LocalizationUtil.getLocalization getting expected value.But this code is working for the xml element value which have plain text unlike & symbol (&).And if any one knows what is the use of unescape() method of HtmlUtil class,please mention.Helping hands are appreciable.